# Access query based on query results

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to Access and queries, however trying to learn fast :)

The project has 2 tables: `tblClientData` contains only data of clients, `tblClientComments` contains all the commentaries made to all clients.

1. Database

   - Table with Clients data called `tblClientData`
   - Table with comments to Clients called `tblClientComments`
   - Form showing all upper data with functionality to find, add or change existing data

I wanted to make an option button - if ticked it would only show certain Clients, when unticked it would show all again. Problem raises here.

Criteria to this query comes from another table (`tblClientComments`) within this database. For example: if Client was contacted by an employee - he is making commentary.

In order to finish this task I need to get all unique IDs from `tblClientComments` and then add each of it as criteria to query `tblClientData`. I tried to make an array with values from `tblClientComments` and then create a query but so far still fighting with syntax.

Or maybe there is another way?

Comment: _..but so far still fighting with syntax_, what have you tried?

Comment: I just want to be sure--when the option button is checked, the query only shows the clients with comments? Also, I expect there may be multiple comments for some clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason that you need VBA to build your query. A simple SQL `IN()` statement should certainly suffice:

```sql
SELECT Client.ID, Client.OtherInfo
FROM tblClientsData As Client WHERE Client.ID IN(SELECT tblClientComments.CustID From tblClientComments)
```

Now, you have a few options. (I'm assuming you're using a checkbox for simplicity.)

1. Assign SQL to the query you're using for your form. Since these changes are dependent on changes to the checkbox, assign a VBA sub to the `After Update` event:

   - Go to Layout View
   - Click on your checkbox
   - Go to the Event tab on the Property Sheet
   - Hit the ... button beside the On Click
   - Hit Code Builder

Now put in some code:

```vb
If(Forms!yourForm!yourCheckbox = True) Then
    CurrentDB.QueryDefs("yourQuery").SQL = "SELECT Client.ID, Client.OtherInfo FROM tblClientsData As Client WHERE Client.ID IN(SELECT Comments.CustID From Comments)"
Else
    CurrentDB.QueryDefs("yourQuery").SQL = "SELECT Client.ID, Client.OtherInfo FROM tblClientsData As Client"
End If
```

You can then just use [`Forms!yourForm.Refresh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836021.aspx) to reflect your changes with the checkbox.

2. An alternate, likely simpler solution might be to use [a filter](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Apply-a-filter-to-view-select-records-in-an-Access-database-2a493ded-e544-4144-9103-b9b1d1865147#__toc254891386) which you turn on/off. [`DoCmd.ApplyFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197651.aspx) should be a very straightforward way to change the form's contents. (Note that the example at the last hyperlink is very similar to your situation.)

Comment: I populate my listboxes with queries so syntax looks slightly different but you made a good point. Since I am beginner in this area, I had no idea I could use WHERE xxxyyyzzz IN. That was excacly what I was after! Thanks a milion! :)

Comment: @Iowak Glad I could help! Check out [this great site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) for more SQL, keeping in mind that Access SQL is kind of its own thing. Most things work, but it's technically not the same as other versions.